# Automapper normailzation for all members

Tags: c#, automapper

Is it there some short way to use an normalization method on all string type properties?

For example I have two classes:

```
public class Text
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

public class TextSource
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

And I would like them to map:

```
[TestMethod]

    public void ShouldMapTextSourceToText()
    {
        var TextSource = new TextSource()
        {
            Content = "<![CDATA[Content]]>",
            Header = "<![CDATA[Header]]>",
        };

        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<TextSource, Text>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Content, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Content.Normalize()))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Header, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Header.Normalize())));

        var text = Mapper.Map<Text>(TextSource);

        Assert.AreEqual("Content", text.Content);
        Assert.AreEqual("Header", text.Header);           
    }
```

Instead of configuring the normalization method for each property individually is it posible to do it once for all properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

Yes, you would use a [custom type converter](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html):

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
        cfg.CreateMap<TextSource, Text>();
        cfg.CreateMap<string, string>().ConvertUsing(s => s.Normalize());
});
```

This tells AutoMapper that whenever it is mapping a string to a string, then apply the `Normalize()` method.

Note that this will apply to **all** string conversions, not just the ones in the `TextSource` to `Text` mapping.